# How to SELECT a column held in a local variable in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a variable holding the column name.
I want to do a select with it like this way

```
select `@x` from table;
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SET @y = CONCAT('SELECT ', @x, ' FROM table;');
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @y;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

Comment: You need a space before your `FROM`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [prepared statement](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html) as follows:

```
SET @x = 'some_field';

SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT ', @x, ' FROM table;');

PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```